# Kineticjs Stage Cordinates after scaling

Tags: html5-canvas, kineticjs

I'm using KineticJS to allow users to free hand drawing shapes on canvas and I am successfully able to zoom in/out canvas stage by setting scale.

Challenge:

Am not getting the updated scaled coordinates values after zoom in/out. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the coordinates don't get scaled, because the only thing you are changing with the 'setScale()' method is the zoom.

So, if you want to know tne coordinates in the scaled stage you probably have to store the scale amount in a variable and when you need a coordinate after scaling, you simply multiply the original shape coordinate with the scale of the stage.

This would be my approach, not sure if there is any other way to do this ;)

Comment: I have the coordinates and scale amount then what should be the formula to calculate the coordinates ?

Comment: To calculate the coordinates, you simply have to multiply the initial coordinate (x and y) with the scale amount.
For example: initial coordinates (400, 100), scale 1.5 
400*1.5 = 600 
100*1.5 = 150 scaled coordinates (600, 150)